# Ubuntu 18.04 freezes randomly

Tags: dual-boot, drivers, nvidia, graphics

My Dell [Inspiron 15 7567 laptop](https://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/19/sln304659/dell-inspiron-15-gaming-7567-usage-and-troubleshooting-guide) with a NVIDIA 1050 ti graphic card and the Nvidia 390 driver freezes randomly in Ubuntu 18.04. It happens every 15-60 minutes.

I had the freezing problem in Windows before, but resolved it in Windows with updates, before I installed Ubuntu in a dual-boot configuration, where Windows boots from an SSD and Ubuntu boots from an HDD.  Other Ubuntu video drivers have been tried, as have multiple complete re-installations of Ubuntu, but the problem persists. Reverting to factory default settings in BIOS/Setup did not solve it.

Disabling browser hardware acceleration reduces the frequency but does not prevent it. Full screen video at multiple websites (other than YouTube) reliably triggers the freeze.  Switching to the onboard Intel display device does not solve it.

Windows CPU temps are typically around 30 degrees Celsius, but Ubuntu runs the machine at 50-60 degrees Celsius. I was able to reduce that to 50 by changing the speed of the fan with i8kutils, but that doesn't affect how often the system freezes.

Here's part of the log file "/var/log/syslog" from when it freezes: 
 https://pastebin.com/t7LXGcwD

Comment: What does the GPU temperature look like (see nvidia-settings)?

Comment: @ubfan1 the GPU temperature looks normal around 50C and btw i am using NVIDIA but even when i switch to intel using nvidia-settings i still have the same problem

Comment: It's a kind of problem you should be reporting, otherwise nobody would even know it exists. I would guess it's something hardware-specific. Does the problem happens only with NVidia or Nouveau drivers, or both?

Comment: FYI, it might be just an odd timing, but Dell has removed information about this notebook from the site. This link that Google still has https://www.dell.com/en-us/shop/cty/pdp/spd/inspiron-15-7567-laptop now redirects to another laptop. I tried to ask Dell support if 7567 was withdrawn because of freezing problems, and described your situation with links. They couldn't answer, and recommended to ask technical support, which requires product id. You can do it though.

Comment: Thanks for answering @ Hi-Angel it happen for both @K7AAy i switched back to intel using nvidia-setting and i did a factory reset for the BIOS and to check if the problem still exist i opened a video online in full screen, it took it more time this time for the laptop to freeze but yep the problem still exist as for the laptop i google my problem and i did saw some people have a problem like me in Linux and they are saying the support for Linux is not great but i will give it a try ;)

Comment: Also i am using dual-boot i did install windows in the ssd drive and Ubuntu in the hard drive