# My system freezes when it's in powersave

Tags: drivers, power-management, cpu, cpufreq

My Dell Inspiron 15 7567 laptop with Intel Core i7-7700HQ and NVIDIA 1050 ti graphic card with the Nvidia 390 driver freezes when I do activities like watch videos in full screen...
I did post about this problem before but I didn't get any solution : [Ubuntu 18.04 freezes randomly](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1057995/ubuntu-18-04-freezes-randomly)

After more investigation it turned out it's due to the CPU, the problem happen only when I am in Powersave if I pick Performance the PC work fine without freezes.

If i pick Performance mode the CPU work on it full power (> 98%) which make the battery drain fast is there a way to fix the Powersave mode and make it stop causing the freezing problem ?

This is the out put of cpufreq-info : https://pastebin.com/60v3heNr

Comment: You can try setting your minimum frequency higher. If it's at 800Mhz set it to 1200 Mhz. :

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix in Powersave mode when I type this command (cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep "MHz") I can see that the the CPU frequency is always at 1400-1500 MHz, I did try different tasks and it never got to 1000 MHz, so not sure if setting the minimum frequency to 1200 will help (I didn't find a clear way to change the minimum frequency xD, when I make the changes it's like nothing happened maybe it's the BIOS override the changes ) Anyway could it be a bug in changing the the CPU state or something and not the frequency ? ( This is the out put of cpufreq-info : https://pastebin.com/60v3heNr )